# Limit moodle login to a specific URL

Tags: moodle

I am trying to write an authentication plugin with moodle such that if this plugin was used for authentication then navigating to any other page than the first requested page should redirect the user to the login page.
I have a page which take a userid and target page URL. When called it loops through all auth plugins including mine. My plugin creates a session and redirects to the target page. Now I need to prevent the user from visiting any other page.
In my page I have this

```
foreach($authsequence as $authname) {
    $authplugin = get_auth_plugin($authname);
    $authplugin->loginpage_hook();
}
```

And in the plugin I have

```
function loginpage_hook() {
        global $CFG, $DB, $USER, $SESSION;
        if ($user = $DB->get_record('user', array('id'=>$USER->id, 'suspended'=>0))) {
            complete_user_login($user);
            $link = $SESSION->wantsurl;
            unset($SESSION->wantsurl);
            redirect($link);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: See here: https://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Site_policies#Force_users_to_login

Comment: Well the auth plugin has already given them a session. So that setting does not work.

Comment: So your concern  is session, instead of closing access to the website?